# How small is *too small* for an opensource project?

Tags: python, open-source, driver, libraries

I have a fair number of smaller projects / libraries that I have been using over the past 2 years.  I am thinking about moving them to Google Code to make it easier to share with co-workers and easier to import them into new projects on my own environments.  The are things like a simple FSMs, CAN (Controller Area Network) drivers, and GPIB drivers.  Most of them are small (less than 500 lines), so it makes me wonder are these types of things *too* small for a stand alone open-source project?

Note that I would like to make it opensource because it does not give me, or my company, any real advantage.

Comment: All you need seems to be a shared code repository, so you could consider using GitHub or something similar.

Comment: I saw one-liners more precious than 200k lines codebase. Why are you measuring value by counting lines of code? I don't get it.

Comment: I think if they solve some sort of problem then they can and should be open sourced.  It seems like the libraries are being used commercially already so they obviously have value to you.

If they have value to you, and someone else may value them as well, you may as well open source them.

Comment: It's your code, you can do whatever you want for it without SO's blessing. Do you have a practical use for putting the code on [code hosting provider of choice]? If you do, then go ahead and do it. I would put my homework on GitHub just in case my hard drive fails.

Comment: If it were posted as a question on SO, would it be closed as too localized? If the answer to that question is yes, then it's too small for open source

Comment: @inspectorG4dget In general I agree, but some highly specialist library that computes "widgets and wotsits" in O(n) time, although extremely localised would still be of  use to people in that field

Comment: Thanks for the comment all.  I wasn't meaning to measure value by the number of lines.  These small drivers / libraries have saved me many many hours over the past few years, I'm just new to contributing to the open-source community and was unsure if it made any since to share them in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller the better.

A 10 line function to convert HSV to RGB or find the closest point to a triangle or something like a CAN/GPIB driver is far more likely to be read and used than a massive complicated poorly documented framework

Answer (score 1):

Do not think about number of lines of code, think about utility of your code. If your code is useful for somebody, upload your code to a repository or repositories, write wiki, examples, etc. I saw a useful Python library that was less than 100 lines.

Answer (score 0):

500 lines? That's a lot in my opinion.

Sounds just fine to publish them as a project. I mean how many blog posts have you read with just some code that saved you hours?

Now imagine that but 500 lines of code and a permanent host designed for the purpose